# Why data write isn't validated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database that's structured like this:

```
flairs
   |_____User1
   |        |__x: 1
   |        |__y: 1
   |        |__z: 1
   |
   |_____User2
            |__x: 1
            |__y: 1
            |__z: 1
```

I want to validate that when a user updates his x, y, and z data that each one of them is a number and that they're all in a certain range. I wrote the following rules:

```
 "flairs": {
      "$user": {
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['x','y','z']) &&
                      newData.child('x').isNumber() &&
                      newData.child('x').val() > -2 &&
                      newData.child('x').val() < 11 &&
                      newData.child('y').isNumber() &&
                      newData.child('y').val() > -2 &&
                      newData.child('y').val() < 8 &&
                      newData.child('z').isNumber() &&
                      newData.child('z').val() > 0 &&
                      newData.child('z').val() < 4"
      }
    }
```

Basically I check the new data has x, y, and z children and that they're all integers in a certain range. However, when I try write the following data in `flairs/User1` I get a write denied even though the user is authenticated:

```
{
  "User1": {"x":1,"y":2,"z":1}
}
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Here is a picture of my simulator:
[image: sim]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing to path `/flairs/User1` and you're writing:

```
{
  "User1": {"x":1,"y":2,"z":1}
}
```

So the final result will be `/flairs/User1/Users/x`, etc. That is not valid according to your rules.

You'll want to write:

```
{"x":1,"y":2,"z":1}
```

Comment: and as usual Frank comes to the rescue... thanks for the response and being so active in the community.